# Is there a way to make an exception for the same error if the previous exception raises an error?

Tags: python, exception

Is there a way to make an exception for the same error if the previous exception raises an error? I know this example doesn't make sense, but it's the easiest way to demonstrate what I mean. For example:

```
import string

a = input('')
try:
    print(str(int(a)+1))
except ValueError:
    print(string.punctuation.index(a))
```

Is there a way to work it so if it isn't a number, it goes to `except ValueError` to run if it is in `string.punctuation`, but then if that raises a `ValueError` then it goes to another `except ValueError` to say that it isn't a number or symbol? etc. something like this but in a code that works:

```
import string

a = input('')
try:
    print(str(int(a)+1))
except ValueError:
    print(string.punctuation.index(a))
except ValueError:
        print('Not a number or symbol!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another `try` block within the `except` to catch the second `ValueError`.

```
import string

a = input()  # no need for an empty arg
try:
    print(int(a) + 1)  # no need for explicit str conversion
except ValueError:
    try:
        print(string.punctuation.index(a))
    except ValueError:
        print('Not a number or symbol!')
```